# Textmate's Ruby on Rails 3 bundle?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I couldn't find Rails3 bundle for Textmate. 
I looked at their website (as well as their github).
I couldn't find any!!

THanks!

Adam

Comment: I stopped using TextMate a while ago so I can't be sure, but I doubt they would have a separate bundle for Rails 3, and would instead just make the changes in the normal Rails bundle.

Answer (score 15):

The Ruby on Rails bundle (http://github.com/drnic/ruby-on-rails-tmbundle) supports Rails 2 & 3

Comment: Though its generate ui seems to still be invoking old rails 2 scripts, so generate stuff doesn't work.